# FFMPEG: Batch file to map multiple streams into single mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, batch

Been around this for hours without any luck.

I'm trying to convert the following command:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "%1" -i "%~n1_a0.aac" -i "%~n1_a1.aac" -i "%~n1_a2.aac" -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~n1"_new.mp4
```

Into something that can take any number of aac files, either by dragging the mp4 file or all of them onto a batch file.

Tried using tee muxer but I guess that only works for output files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FFmpeg needs all specified inputs to be found, so you'll have to implement this in the batch file.

Comment: MurderOfPoes.... A couple things: `1.` try using a syntax of `ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "%1" -i "%~fn1_a0.aac" -i "%~fn1_a1.aac" -i "%~fn1_a2.aac" -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~fn1_new.mp4"` and if it works, I'm glad to add an answer explaining why assuming you are dragging only 1 file into this batch script and you know for sure that the other `acc` files within that same folder of the file you just dragged all 3 of those also exist.

Comment: The problem with dragging a group into a batch, you don't really know the order they will be passed and the arguments need appropriate placeholders represented as `%~fn1`, `%~fn2`, and `%~fn3` for example. Again, I'm not certain what the default order is based on file name chronologically sorted, etc. so you'll need to consider this and put logic into the script to adjust accordingly perhaps but not sure. Hopefully `#1` will suffice and you'll be all set. Tag me back as `@PimpJuiceIT` when you get a chance and let me know how it goes, etc. and I'm happy to take further action to assist.